# Data received via sockets can't be used C++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

so I'm getting socket communication, AND I'm getting the proper message...however when I try to extract it from the receive buffer...it doesn't work. My code looks something like this:

```
void CClientSocket::OnReceive(int nErrorCode) 
{
    char buff[1000];
    int ibuf = Receive(buff,sizeof(buff));
    buff[sizeof(buff)-1] ='\0';
    CSocket::OnReceive(nErrorCode);
}
```

When I run in debug, the value of buff contains the proper message...along with a bunch of random characters filling up the unused portion of the array. However, I can't use that data...if I try to convert to CString or even to transfer the characters to a different array...nothing works. I'm baffled and I really don't know what to do.

Let me know if you need more info or if I am unclear in any way.

**EDIT: some code I have tried to extract the data**

```
CString string;
string = CString(buff);
```

AND

```
char *msg;
msg = new char[ibuf]
for(int i = 0; i < ibuf; i++){
    msg[i] = (char)buff[i];
}
```

**EDIT: some clarification**
when i said 'nothing works' I meant that when I tried to convert it, the result was and empty CString or empty char etc...there are no errors.

Comment: Can you post relevant code that doesn't work? i.e.: when you try to "convert to CString"?

Comment: That's probably why they invented `std::string` :D

Comment: We are programmers capable of understanding error messages.  Don't just say "nothing works".  Obviously something does work if you write your code correctly.

Comment: "the result was and empty CString or empty char" -- Are you sure you're not just copying a NULL as the first character and then not being able to see anything after it? Try looking at the memory in the debugger directly and see what's there.

Comment: @spencercw that may very well be the case, how would I get around that if it is?

Comment: @PTBG Well it depends on what you're doing. If you shouldn't be receiving a NULL character in your stream you should investigate as to why one is being sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int ibuf = Receive(buff,sizeof(buff));
buff[sizeof(buff)-1] ='\0';
```

Rather than that second line, put the zero byte at `buff[ibuf]`.  But before that, add an error check (make sure `ibuf > 0` and if not, treat it as a connection drop.)  Also, if you do it this way you should `Receive(buff, sizeof(buff)-1);` (note the `-1` - this accounts for the terminating character - thanks @Altnitak for pointing this out.)

On the other hand...  I would also argue that this is no way to treat socket code.  Strings are not sent atomically over the network.  They will be split.  If you control the protocol, I suggest you depart the string-centered view of the universe, and structure your network communications so that messages begin with an integer (`uint16_t` or `uint32_t`, and make sure to call `htons`/`htonl` etc.) indicating the length of the payload that follows.  Then keep buffering incoming bytes and process them when you have enough to satisfy the lengths specified.

If you do not control the protocol, find a convenient marker that you can use to decide when to process content, and buffer bytes until you reach it.  (For example if you're doing HTTP, you might buffer chars until you see a newline while processing headers, then decide on a certain buffer size for the contents of the response...)

Comment: 1.  you need to account for `ibuf == sizeof(buff)`  2.  re atomic sends, etc?  irrelevant if it's a TCP socket.

Comment: @Alnitak - No it's not irrelevant.  You can't `write(fd, foo, len)` and assume that the other end will get exactly `len` returned from `read`.  They might get the first `n` bytes in one call to `read` and then `len - n`  in the next call.

Comment: right, I see what you mean, except he's not asking for `len`, he's asking for `sizeof(buff)`, i.e. 1000 bytes.  If it's TCP, the system will damn well try and read that much, even if he has written less than that, i.e. the system will return the required volume of data from the stream, not constrained by the packet boundaries.